# Should a common noun which has a specific word in a different language be capitalised?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

The setting is that there is a celebration underway where people of different species (lets say, humans and elves) are attending. In the elves' language they call **any** celebration "*Jashnak*". So, if they are welcoming someone they would say "Welcome to the Jashnak!" but then I am not sure how subsequent references should be handled ?

For e.g.
In case of a third party observer

> The lanterns hovered above the marquee where the Jashnak was underway.

In case of two humans talking

> The Jashnak sure is getting rowdy!

OR

> Come on... Get ready quickly. We have a Jashnak to attend.

If I was to use "celebration" instead of "Jashnak", the celebration in the two examples would not be capitalised (on account that it is a common noun).

Comment: You can do capitalization, but then it will be hard for you to escape the idea that "Jashnak" is a very specific holiday.

Comment: Farsang,is a wish away the winter party that can happen anytime in January or February. It's not as generic as party, yet it isn't as specific as Christmas. In Hungarian I've only seen it in lower case, in English I've only seen it capitalized.

Comment: @Allan, good point. The capitalization rules may differ between languages. For instance, week and month names are capitalized in English, not so in Swedish.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether you want the word to come across as **specific**, in which case you *would* capitalize, versus a **general** word, in which case you *don't* capitalize. To explain what I mean, consider if I referred to "the Queen," versus "the queen." The former suggests that I am referring to a specific queen, with a specific title and identity; the latter suggests that I'm just referring to the title itself in a general sense. This is the subtle, but noticeable effect that choosing whether or not to capitalize a word creates.

Therefore, if you want Jashnak to sound like an official, specific event and not just a word in a language, capitalize it. But if you want jashnak to sound like a word for "party" in a more general sense, lowercase it.

Comment: I agree with your points but one thing I realised just now is that the problem is perspective. For the elves, the event is common and general but for the humans, it is special and specific (probably the only one they will attend in their lifetime). So will it be OK then to refer in capital when humans are talking and lower case when referred by elves ? But what if it is from the narrator's perspective (like setting a scene) ?